# Trouble w/ Meteor Sorting

Tags: sorting, dynamic, meteor, collections

I'm trying to add a simple drop down control above a list such that I can sort it by "created" or "title".

The list template is called `posts_list.html`.  In it's helper .js file I have:

```
posts: function () {
  var sortCriteria = Session.get("sortCriteria") || {};
  return Posts.find({},{sort: {sortCriteria: 1}});
}
```

Then, I have abstracted the list into another template.  From here I have the following click event tracker in the `helper.js`

```
"click": function () {
  // console.log(document.activeElement.id);
  Session.set("sortCriteria", document.activeElement.id);
  // Router.go('history');
  Router.render('profile');
}
```

Here I can confirm that the right Sort criteria is written to the session. However, I can't make the page refresh.  The collection on the visible page never re-sorts.

Frustrating.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks so much for that.  Note I've left commented out code below to show what I pulled out.  If I required a truly dynamic option, versus the simply binary below, I would have stuck w/ the "var options" approach.  What I ended up going with was:

```
    Template.postList.helpers({


    posts: function () {

        //var options = {};

        if (Session.get("post-list-sort")) {

            /*options.sort = {};
             if (Session.get("post-list-sort") == "Asc") {
             options.sort['created'] = 1;
             } else {
             options.sort['created'] = -1;
             }*/
            //return hunts.find({}, options);}

            console.log(Session.get("hunt-list-sort"));
            if (Session.get("hunt-list-sort") == "Asc") {
                return Hunts.find({}, {sort: {title: 1}});
            }
            else {
                return Hunts.find({}, {sort: {title: -1}});
            };
        }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables as keys in an object literal. Give this a try:

```js
posts: function() {
  var sortCriteria = Session.get('sortCriteria');
  var options = {};
  if (sortCriteria) {
    options.sort = {};
    options.sort[sortCriteria] = 1;
  }
  return Posts.find({}, options);
}
```

Also see the "Variables as keys" section of [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).